# What does `cat -` mean in this snippet?

Tags: cat

```
echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &
cat <pipe2 > pipe1
```

Comes from article http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html ?

Comment: `-` means standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` first produces "x" from stdin (`-`), then whatever named `pipe1` offers.

Following it with that 2nd cat command is pretty wild, as the "x" bounces around between two cat's. Vaught in 1997 explained:

> both cat programs are running like crazy copying the letter x back and forth in an endless loop.